# composer problems with installing Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I got the following error when run

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel=5.2 job --prefer-dist
```

however when I don't specifiy the version of laravel it works fine,

I tried to do `composer clearcache` but It does not fix the error :(

here is the error:

```
> php -r "copy('.env.example', '.env');"
> php artisan clear-compiled

Warning: require(C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\jobsapi\job\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\jobsapi\job\boo
tstrap\autoload.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required 'C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\jobsapi\job\bootstrap/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\lara
vel\jobsapi\job\bootstrap\autoload.php on line 17
Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the pre-update-cmd event returned with error code 255
```

in spite of the error Laravel 5.2 is partially installed by the vendor folder is missing

Answer (score 0):

it can't find the autoload files in the vendor directory, so you should run

```
composer install
```

to pull in all the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing something there..
Create project by running this..

```
composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel yourDirectory "5.2.*"
```

from the [official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2)

Comment: tried as well, but get the same error, gave up already and using 5.3

Comment: yes it works fine when I don't specify the version , like that:               composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel yourDirectory

Comment: if at all you want `laravel 5.2`, go to your `composer.json`, edit the `"laravel/framework:5.3"` to `5.2` and run `composer update laravel/framework`

Answer (score 0):

Vendor must be installed  when downloading Laravel framework. The most common problem is the version of php that you are using. First you need to make sure your server requirements for Laravel are met. I recommend you change the version of php to Php version 7. You can find out which php modules are installed by typing: php-m Then you need to run the following commands:

1. sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
2. sudo apt-get install phpunit
3. composer update